# I can't get .each() to work with each of my images

Tags: jquery, each

Please could someone help me figure out where I am going wrong.

I am basically trying to put an image within a div, and trying to get jQuery to work out each image's height, and then dividing it by 2, and then that final ***number*** will be used in my css like so  Top: calc( 50% - ***number*** );

https://jsfiddle.net/q3cu92xr/

```js
    $(document).ready(tophalfcalcfn);
    $(window).on('resize',tophalfcalcfn);
    
     
    function tophalfcalcfn() {
     $('.gallery img').each(function () {
       var halfImgHeight = parseInt($(".gallery img").height()) / 2;
       $('.gallery img').css( { top: 'calc(50% - ' + halfImgHeight + 'px)' } );
     });
    };
```

```css
    .page {
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #eaeaea;
    }
    
    .gallery-outer-row {
        padding: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #0000003b;
        max-width: 780px;
        margin-top: 40px;
    }
    
    .gallery {
        height: 160px;
        width: 31%;
        margin: 0px 1%;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .gallery img {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        max-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
    
       <div class="gallery-outer-row">
        
          <div class="gallery">
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/08/19/10/16/nature-3616194_960_720.jpg">
          </div>
    
          <div class="gallery">
              <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1366919/pexels-photo-1366919.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=landscape-photography-of-snowy-mountain-1366919.jpg&fm=jpg">
          </div>
    
          <div class="gallery">
              <img src="https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/270000/nahled/beautiful-landscape-15304537867Pa.jpg">
          </div>
          
      </div>
      
    </div>
```

I have gotten the jQuery to work out the number and subtract it from the top position, but it seems to only get the number from the first image and apply it to all 3 of them and when I have tried to use .each() I am evidently doing something wrong because it is not working.

Lastly I understand I can use background-size: cover & background-position: 50% 50%; but in this scenario I need to use a HTML img tag.

Any help will be much appreicated
Thankyou

Comment: Within the each function, use $(this) instead of $('.gallery img')

Comment: I tried that, it never taken affect unless I changed the first 2 of them to $(each), in which case it gave me a random number which changed all of them together

Answer (score 3):

Each `.gallery` element has only one image. You need to loop over the `.gallery` elements instead:

```
$('.gallery').each(function () {
    var halfImgHeight = parseInt($(this).children('img').height()) / 2;
    $(this).children('img').css( { top: 'calc(50% - ' + halfImgHeight + 'px)' } );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simplify you code using parameters in the each function like this :

```
function tophalfcalcfn() {
    $('.gallery img').each(function (i, img) {
    var halfImgHeight = parseInt($(img).height()) / 2;          
     $(img).css( { top: 'calc(50% - ' + halfImgHeight + 'px)' } );  
}); 
};
```